# Gnome 3 Reconfigured Nautilus! How Do I Get It Back to Normal?

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, 15.10

I just tried Gnome 3, but didn't like it at all. So I removed/purged it, rebooted, and discovered that my Nautilus looks different now & lacks a menu. I couldn't even find a way to bring it back to it's normal appearance. How do I get it back to normal without reinstalling the whole OS? I'm very unhappy with this, since there is missing functionality (or at least it's hidden and I can't find it)!

Comment: With the guest account do you have the same problem? What exactly did you remove/purge? Probably some packages are shared, so you should pay attention to what you installed exactly and then what you removed.

Comment: Did you ever resolve the issue? Another user is [having the same issue](http://askubuntu.com/q/856196/).

Answer (score 1):

Since `ubuntu-desktop` depends on `nautilus`, you can and should re-install that as well to avoid future problems:

```
sudo apt-get install -f ubuntu-desktop
```

This will install Nautilus as a side-effect.

You can also just reinstall Nautilus with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

Comment: Tried both, but it says Nautilus can't be reinstalled and the Ubuntu Desktop says it's already the latest version. I rebooted, just to see if maybe something would update once I did that. Still, nothing was fixed.

Comment: Why can `nautilus` not be re-installed? Can you please include the output of `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus` in your question and give me a ping?